# Unable to redirect traffic using Djangae

Tags: python, django, djangae

I am attempting to use [djangae](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae-scaffold) to serve static files only. In addition, I want to route all traffic to an `index.html`. When I visit http://localhost:8000 I get a 500 error. When I visit http://localhost:8000/static/index.html, I get the correct file.

What am I doing wrong?

My `urlpatterns` are as follows:

```
...
from . import views
...
urlpatterns = (
    ...

    url(r'^', views.home),
)
```

I have tried `r'^$'`, `r'^.*$'`, and `''`, but I do not get any difference in the outcome.

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def home(request):
    return redirect('/static/index.html', permanent=True)
```

**500 Error**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 493, in <module>
    for l in open(os.path.join(_tzinfo_dir, 'zone.tab'))
  File "/git_repos/djangae/proj/sitepackages/dev/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 260, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab'
```

Comment: `IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab'` check the permissions on this file.

Comment: 644 and it does exist. In the gae standard environment, this file is being sandboxed restricted - hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a work around in this particular aspect. I moved the `zone.tab` file to `<project_name>/` and edited my app.yaml to include this environment variable: `PYTZ_TZDATADIR: <project_name>`.

Still unsure why pytz needs to be called before a route is completed.